# next android activity

Tags: android

I am beginner in android. I have a login and then I want to run the following file Mainscreenactivity but not how the login says ok but does not show after Mainscreenactivity

login.java

```
        package test.Droidlogin;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import test.Droidlogin.library.Httppostaux;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.SystemClock;
    import android.os.Vibrator;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Login extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    EditText user;
    EditText pass;
    Button blogin;
    TextView registrar;
    Httppostaux post;
    // String URL_connect="http://www.scandroidtest.site90.com/acces.php";
    String IP_Server="10.0.2.2";//IP DE NUESTRO PC
    String URL_connect="http://10.0.2.2/droidlogin/acces.php";//ruta en donde estan nuestros archivos

    boolean result_back;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        post=new Httppostaux();

        user= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edusuario);
        pass= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edpassword);
        blogin= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Blogin);
        registrar=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_register);

        //Login button action
        blogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View view){

                //Extreamos datos de los EditText
                String usuario=user.getText().toString();
                String passw=pass.getText().toString();

                //verificamos si estan en blanco
                if( checklogindata( usuario , passw )==true){

                    //si pasamos esa validacion ejecutamos el asynctask pasando el usuario y clave como parametros

                new asynclogin().execute(usuario,passw);                               


                }else{
                    //si detecto un error en la primera validacion vibrar y mostrar un Toast con un mensaje de error.
                    err_login();
                }

            }
                                                            });

        registrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View view){

                //Abre el navegador al formulario adduser.html
                String url = "http://10.0.2.2/droidlogin/adduser.html";
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);               
                                        }           
                                                                });

    }

    //vibra y muestra un Toast
    public void err_login(){
        Vibrator vibrator =(Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(200);
        Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error:Nombre de usuario o password incorrectos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast1.show();      
    }


    /*Valida el estado del logueo solamente necesita como parametros el usuario y passw*/
    public boolean loginstatus(String username ,String password ) {
        int logstatus=-1;


        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postparameters2send= new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                    postparameters2send.add(new BasicNameValuePair("usuario",username));
                    postparameters2send.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));

           //realizamos una peticion y como respuesta obtenes un array JSON
            JSONArray jdata=post.getserverdata(postparameters2send, URL_connect);

            /*como estamos trabajando de manera local el ida y vuelta sera casi inmediato
             * para darle un poco realismo decimos que el proceso se pare por unos segundos para poder
             * observar el progressdialog
             * la podemos eliminar si queremos
             */
            SystemClock.sleep(950);

            //si lo que obtuvimos no es null
                if (jdata!=null && jdata.length() > 0){

                    JSONObject json_data; //creamos un objeto JSON
                    try {
                        json_data = jdata.getJSONObject(0); //leemos el primer segmento en nuestro caso el unico
                         logstatus=json_data.getInt("logstatus");//accedemos al valor 
                         Log.e("loginstatus","logstatus= "+logstatus);//muestro por log que obtuvimos
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }                   

                    //validamos el valor obtenido
                     if (logstatus==0){// [{"logstatus":"0"}] 
                         Log.e("loginstatus ", "invalido");
                         return false;
                     }
                     else{// [{"logstatus":"1"}]
                         Log.e("loginstatus ", "valido");
                         return true;
                     }

              }else{    //json obtenido invalido verificar parte WEB.
                         Log.e("JSON  ", "ERROR");
                        return false;
              }

    }


    //validamos si no hay ningun campo en blanco
    public boolean checklogindata(String username ,String password ){

    if  (username.equals("") || password.equals("")){
        Log.e("Login ui", "checklogindata user or pass error");
    return false;

    }else{

        return true;
    }

}           

    class asynclogin extends AsyncTask< String, String, String > {

        String user,pass;
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //para el progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Autenticando....");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            //obtnemos usr y pass
            user=params[0];
            pass=params[1];

            //enviamos y recibimos y analizamos los datos en segundo plano.
            if (loginstatus(user,pass)==true){                      
                return "ok"; //login valido
            }else{          
                return "err"; //login invalido                    
            }

        }

        /*Una vez terminado doInBackground segun lo que halla ocurrido 
        pasamos a la sig. activity
        o mostramos error*/
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

           pDialog.dismiss();//ocultamos progess dialog.
           Log.e("onPostExecute=",""+result);

           if (result.equals("ok")){

                Intent i=new Intent(Login.this, HiScreen.class);
                i.putExtra("user",user);
                startActivity(i); 

            }else{
                err_login();
            }

                                                    }

        }

    }




    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

MainscreenActivity.java

```
package test.Droidlogin;




import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainScreenActivity extends Activity{



    Button btnViewProducts;
    Button btnNewProduct;

    boolean result_back;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {






        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Buttons
        btnViewProducts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnViewProducts);
        btnNewProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

        // view products click event
        btnViewProducts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Launching All products Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        // view products click event
        btnNewProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Launching create new product activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewProductActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? It is not clear.

Comment: your question is very likely to get close. It very difficult to understand what you are trying to ask in the question. Rephrase your quesetion and add some meaning to it.

Comment: your code points to HiScreen, not MainScreenActivity

Answer (score 2):

> I have a login and then I want to run the following file Mainscreenactivity but not how the login says ok but does not show after Mainscreenactivity

From your question what I understand is,

```
if (result.equals("ok")){
    Intent i=new Intent(Login.this, HiScreen.class);
    i.putExtra("user",user);
    startActivity(i); 
}
```

In above code, Intent should be,

```
Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, MainscreenActivity.class);
```

Actually you are starting activity `HiScreen` not a `MainscreenActivity`.

Answer (score 2):

```
In manifest.xml

 <activity
            android:name=".MainscreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"/>

In login.java

if (result.equals("ok")){

                Intent intent=new Intent(Login.this,MainscreenActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("user",user);
                startActivity(intent); 

            }else{
                err_login();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write below code lines

```
Intent i=new Intent(Login.this, MainscreenActivity.class);
i.putExtra("user",user);
startActivity(i);
```

instead of

```
Intent i=new Intent(Login.this, HiScreen.class);
i.putExtra("user",user);
startActivity(i);
```

and add MainscreenActivity into androidmanifest file.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainscreenActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main" />
```

it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException)) 
 ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1955 
 this is the error

Answer (score 0):

for string match use  equalsIgnoreCase and check your response is return ok, and your class name declare in Menifest or not.

```
   if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("ok")){

        Intent i=new Intent(Login.this,  MainscreenActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("user",user);
        startActivity(i); 

    }else{
        err_login();
    }
```